# Load/read ECG data, denoise, and plot the 12-leas ECG

Tags: python, medical

I have ECG data as .hea and .mat files; this is a 12-lead ECG. I want to load/read these data, denoise the data, and plot/draw the 12-lead ECG (as an original medical examination). Overall, based on the .hea and .mat files, I want to visualize the 12-lead ECG.

These steps work fine (as far as I can tell) to load and denoise the data. However, I have not been able to find the right way to plot the ECG.

```
import wfdb
import scipy.io
import pywt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load ECG data in .hea format
record = wfdb.rdrecord('/JS00001')
signal = record.p_signal.flatten()

# Load ECG data in .mat format
mat_data = scipy.io.loadmat('/JS00001.mat')
signal = mat_data['val'].flatten()

# Denoise the ECG signal using a wavelet-based approach
wavelet = 'db4'  # choose a wavelet function
threshold = 0.1  # choose a threshold value
coefficients = pywt.wavedec(signal, wavelet)
coefficients[1:] = (pywt.threshold(i, threshold*max(i)) for i in coefficients[1:])
denoised_signal = pywt.waverec(coefficients, wavelet)
```

I tried this:

```
# Plot the original and denoised ECG signals
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(signal, label='Original Signal')
plt.plot(denoised_signal, label='Denoised Signal')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Time (ms)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude (mV)')
plt.show()
```

But this plots the amplitude vs time, which is informative but not the standard 12-lead ECG you may see in a clinical setting.

I also tried this, but it still does not show the right image (but closer).

```
ecg_plot.plot_12(mat_data['val'], sample_rate = fs)
```

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your data might not be in millivolts (mV) and could be too large for plotting using the ecg_plot Python package.  Ensure that your ECG data is scaled appropriately. If it's not in millivolts, you might need to rescale it. Then, adjust the scaling of x-axis and y-axis on your graph according to your requirements.